# Resizing gif images using Imageresizer

Tags: c#, imageresizer

I attempted to use imageresizer and the animated gif plugin to resize an animated gif. It did resize but I lost the animation in the process. I did set the format to gif even after following the example given on the site. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks for the response. I should first point out that I am building a desktop application. Here is the code I am using:

```
var fileName = ofdChiImage.FileName;
Dictionary<string, string> versions = new Dictionary<string, string>();
versions.Add("_thumb1", "maxwidth=200&maxheight=200&format=gif");
string basepath = ImageResizer.Util.PathUtils.RemoveExtension(fileName);
foreach (string suffix in versions.Keys)
{
    ImageBuilder.Current.Build(fileName, basepath + suffix, new ResizeSettings(versions[suffix]), false, true);
}
```

Comment: We need more information to help you: (a) The resizer diagnostics page, and (b) the exact code you're using to perform the resize.

Comment: I made an edit with the code fragment.

Comment: Can you share the diagnostics page? That's what tells you if the plugin was installed correctly.

Comment: Its a desktop application. I'm not sure how to go about that.

Comment: You can call Config.Current.WriteDiagnosticsTo(path) to export it.

Comment: Make sure you're installing plugins through code if it's a dekstop app (I.e, `new AnimatedGifs().Install(Config.Current);`

Comment: That last bit fixed it! It's working now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in .NET4+, Console and desktop applications do not automatically load DLLs that are not explicitly referenced through code (even if they are referenced within App.config). Thus for these types of applications we always recommend the code-based (instead of xml-based) installation method for ImageResizer plugins.